# How to call a function while clicking on save button in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In 'order.sale' while calculating the total tax I need to call on function.But the problem is on clicking on the 'save' button than only that function has to call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a function when you click in the save button you will need to override the write and create method as follows:

```
#using the old api:
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    self.your_function(parameters)
    return super(sale_order, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=ctx)

def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    self.your_function(parameters)         
    return super(sale_order, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context=context)
```

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can override `button_dummy` method which recompute the tax amount and add your logic just after clicking on the [(update)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/sale/sale_view.xml#L193) button.

```
@api.multi
def button_dummy(self):
    res = super(sale_order, self).button_dummy()
    # Add your logic here
    return res
```

Comment: what is button_dummy here ?

Comment: @phani the method called when you click on update button.check my edit to view the code on github.